# Filter rows according to date variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to filter a data.frame either by the column "Date" or "ID".

```
date <- seq(as.POSIXct(strptime("2016-02-01 23:59:59", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),by="month",length.out=3)-86400
df <- data.frame(Date = date, ID = c(1, 2, 3))
select <- "ID"

df %>% filter_(paste(select, "==", 1))
```

This works fine, however when I try to filter for the POSIXct-Date:

```
select <- "Date"
df %>% filter_(paste(select, "==", date[1]))
```

I get an error message. Any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `df %>% filter(ID == 1)` and `df %>% filter(Date == date[1])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are spaces in your date object, it must be quoted. One quick workaround would be this:

```
df %>% filter_(paste(select, "== \'", date[1],"\'"))
```